# Index of arrays and strings in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I want to know from where the index of a string and an array starts from.
I am getting a lot of confusion while making programs.

While calculating string length of a string is the null character also counted?

Comment: Just to say: using *question marks* at the end of your questions might increase the readability; especially for the non-native english speakers.

Comment: actually, the question contains a possibly not intended restriction. If you index an array, then in fact the index starts at 0. But if you index on a pointer, you can in fact do `array[-1]`, provided the pointer points to suitable memory.

Comment: @Schaub, let's keep things simple, shall we? Even though it may be "legal" to use an array to reference contents not in the array, doesn't mean it is a sensible or smart thing to do. The only truly reasonable interpretation is how to access the contents of the array; not how to access arbitrary memory with it.

Comment: @Michael, i'm not sure what you want to say by "use an array to reference contents not in the array". Haven't said such a thing. Neither did i say how to access "arbitrary memory". I merely said you can index by using numbers less than 0, if you have a pointer offset from the start of an array, like `int a[2] = { 0, 1 }; int b = (&a[1])[-1];`

Comment: Schaubs comment actually includes an insight WHY indices start from zero when programming. It is because indices are used as offsets when addressing into the array, therefore zero offset means beginning of the array.

Comment: there's also `a[1] == 1[a]` (always true) ;)

Answer (score 3):

In C, C++, Java, and Python, array indices are 0-based, so they range from 0 to length-1. Some mathematically-oriented programming languages such as Matlab are 1-based. As a general rule of thumb, "real programming languages" tend to use 0-based indexing; mathematical/protoyping/modeling languages or other domain-specific languages may use 0-based or 1-based indexing, with 1-based common for math.

In terms of strings, the length of a string usually refers to the number of characters in the string excluding the terminating NUL-character, while the length of the *buffer* refers to the entire buffer's length, including the terminating NUL. You will find that [std::string::size()](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/size) and [strlen()](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/strlen.html) return the number of characters in the string, excluding the terminating NUL (i.e. the string length). The length of the buffer is actually one more than that.

Answer (score 2):

The index starts from ZERO.

Comment: then i also want to know whether null character is also counted while calculating string length of a string.

Comment: If you wish to iterate through the string's character in the fashion of a char * in that case, the '\n' will also be there. The array of char will be of length equal to the length of the string PLUS one.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear what you're asking.

If you're asking whether strings and arrays start at index 0, then Yes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroth